# FFMPEG resize while encoding with hwaccel (C++)

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I am encoding a video that I generate from an OpenGL texture, and send it to an RTP stream (with h264_nvenc) and it works pretty well except for one thing: I would like to resize the stream  without recreating the whole encoding pipeline, is that even possible?

What I tried until now is to recreate a new codec context and hwframe and use them in `avcodec_send_frame` and `avcodec_receive_packet`, but after that I get a framerate drop and encoder complains about packets timestamps.

Thanks.

Comment: You can change the timestamps of the AVFrames before calling `avcodec_send_frame`

Comment: I already do that, but when I try to encode with the new codec, then the packets have inconsistent timestamps, i.e. `dts > pts` (and then ffmpeg is not happy). I also tried to manually change the packets timestamps, and that removes the error, but the stream then shows only black frames...